# In jQuery mobile, How to preserve selections of a form that is dynamically brought into DOM?

Tags: jquery, json, forms, selection, preserve

I'm using "Navigation" toolbar of jquery mobile to load different tab contents. The tab content consists of JSON data brought in through ajax.

I'm able to do following process:
Pull json data and manipulate the DOM and enhance it in jquery mobile look upon click of a certain navigation element. However, from the subsequent navigation click, form selection isn't preserved. I don't want to preserve the selections in database or cookies as those are not in the application specs. So that leaves me with caching on the client-side in a variable.

Any ideas/suggestions/advise is appreciated!

Comment: By "selections" you mean inputs into a `select` form field?

Comment: Oh.. I meant selections made on radiobox and checkbox etc...